# Как выяснить, что элементы потомки одного родителя?

Tags: javascript

Коллеги, есть два блока с одинаковым классом, в которых по два блока с одинаковым классом

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.child')].forEach(s => {
  console.log("s", s);
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child-1</div>
  <div class="child">Child-2</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child-3</div>
  <div class="child">Child-4</div>
</div>
```

Как выяснить, что

`<div class="child">Child-3</div> <div class="child">Child-4</div>`

потомки одного родителя?

> P.S. Хочу отметить важную вещь, не стоит предлагать присвоить им
>   другой ***class*** в ручную или определять по ***ID***. Так как для
>   этого и хочу выяснить, чтобы программно присвоить каждому родителю
>   разные ***class-ы***, их более пятисот и в ручную не вариант....

И еще, один момент. Дочерних элементов может быть и больше двух или даже один...

Чтобы было более понятнее, вопрос конкретизирую...

Есть куча элементов `.parent` в которых ***N-е*** количество элементов `.child`.

Ho может быть и такое

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child-3</div>
  <div class="child">Child-4</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="some-other-class">Some other class</div>
  <div class="some-other-class">Some other class</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child-3</div>
  <div class="child">Child-4</div>
</div>
```

Когда есть элемент `.parent`, в котором нет дочернего элемента `.child`, учитывать их не надо...

Comment: `if ( elem1.parentNode === elem2.parentNode) { console.log('bingo')}`

Comment: можно сравнить ссылки на `parentNode`, но мне кажется это проблема XY

Comment: после дополнения вопроса вообще перестал что-либо понимать. Вам необходимо сравнить все `.child` со всеми `.child`? А смысл? Почему бы просто не находить `.parent` и в них `.child`. Зачем в обратную сторону нужно искать?

Comment: @Алексей, в том то и дело, что я сам запутался уже...

Comment: @Air дайте более полное объяснение. Мне кажется (может я заблуждаюсь, потому что не до конца понимаю задачу), `.parent` проще найти, а дальше проверить его `.child` по какому-то условию и сделать что-то с `.parent`. Или же вы хотите сделать что-то с `.child`, но и тут мне кажется проще найти `.parent`, а в нем нужных `.child`. Извините, но для меня все туманно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть, что-то около того:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.parent')].forEach( (elem, index) => { 
  [...elem.querySelectorAll('.child')].forEach(chld => {
    console.log( 'Потомок parent номер ' + index + ' — ',
                  chld,
                 '\n// Всего таких: ' + elem.querySelectorAll('.child').length + ' шт' );
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child-0</div>
  <div class="child">Child-1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="some-other-class">Some other class</div>
  <div class="some-other-class">Some other class</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child-2</div>
  <div class="child">Child-3</div>
  <div class="child">Child-4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

я представляю что-то такое

```
function commonParent(firstElemSelector, secondElemSelector) {
    var first = document.querySelector(firstElemSelector);
    var second = document.querySelector(secondElemSelector);

    return first.parentElement === second.parentElement;
}

console.log(commonParent('.firstElem', '.secondElem'));
```

p.s. исправлен по совету, опытных товарищей ниже

Comment: последние 2 строчки функции можно безболезнено заменить на 
`return first.parentElement === second.parentElement`

Comment: @Дмытрык исправил ответ, по вашему совету. На более чистый и лаконичный